# Windows Phone 7 Device Info and Filesystem Info from PC Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-7

I would like to develop a Windows 7 Desktop Application, which should provide the following information by talking to Windows Phone 7.0. It is un-locked/refurbished phones.

IMEI number
Filesystem info such as(contacts, calendar entries and call log entries etc.)
Setup: Desktop App -----USB------- Windows Phone 7

Please share some information on how to retrieve the said information.

Comment: Perhaps the code of Windows Phone Power Tools (http://wptools.codeplex.com) might provide some direction.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for pointing out the link. However I was able to access the Device Information and Images/videos/Audio files. But I want to access the contacts/calendar/call-logs on the Windows Phone 7 from desktop. Any idea/pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any more than that. I posted the link because it's an open source project of a desktop app that pulls information from the phone.

Comment: So far I have tried MTP Device Services, however WP7 Devices doesn't support these services it seems. Also I have tried WPD(Windows Portable Device) functions to retrieve only images/audio/folders. Not the Contacts, Calendar and Call Logs.